# Why is my mixer tap/faucet slow to switch off?

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink, taps

I have a 4-year-old mixer tap/faucet in my kitchen, and until recently the water would stop flowing immediately when the tap was switched off.

[image: the tap/faucet]

Now the water continues to flow for a few seconds when the tap is closed.

I wasn't able to buy the exact cartridge (left image) so I tried a generic spare part (right image), but the behaviour is the same with the new cartridge. The gaps aren't identical, which may be the reason the new cartridge hasn't helped?

[image: old and new cartridges]

The metal filter/aerator at the end of the spout is clean. The tap underneath the bench is fully on, and the pressure is good.

What do I need to change in order for the water to stop flowing immediately when the tap is closed?

Comment: is this happening on both sides? (hot/cold)

Comment: did you disassemble the aerator before this started happening? ....... the only thing that i can think of, is that the aerator had a fine mesh that kept air out by way of surface tension of water and now the mesh is gone, so air gets in and water drains out

Comment: yes, this happens with hot/cold. I didn't disassemble the aerator before it started happening, but perhaps it has failed? The bathroom tap has a similar long metal spout, but with separate hot/cold taps instead of a mixer - the water stops flowing immediately when the tap is closed, with or without the aerator in place, which makes me think that it's not the aerator's job to stop the water flowing(?)

Comment: i was only guessing at the aerator ..... are you absolutely sure that the tap did not drain in the past the same way that it drains now?  ..... maybe it is a case of `jamais vu` ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamais_vu

Comment: @jsotola I wasn't sure so I tested a friend's kitchen tap - it definitely stops flowing immediately ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but .... the problem started spontaneously, and has just as spontaneously resolved itself.

I didn't make any changes, as I re-used the original cartridge, but the tap now behaves normally a few months after the problem started.

Presumably the cause was external to the tap, perhaps related to the water pressure, etc.